# Shorten data numbers in tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable

I want to shorten the numbers on json / datatable.

I take json data from a website, but json on the website displays very detailed figures.

For example: json displays 408.43324032. and I want to display only 408 or 408x.

[image]

---

I want to show it like this.

Is there a reference? I don't know what the name is to make this kind of thing.

[image]

any help & reference will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you might be looking for `Math.round()` or `.toPrecision()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Comment: Thank you. That seems right.. it's possible for datatable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
console.log( 408.73324032.toFixed(0) )    // Fix and round to nearest
console.log( 408.73324032.toFixed(1) )    // Fix at 1 decimal and round to nearest
console.log( Math.round(408.73324032) )   // round to nearest
console.log( Math.floor(408.73324032) )   // round to lowest
console.log( Math.ceil(408.73324032) )    // round to upper
console.log( parseInt(408.73324032, 10) ) // integer only (radix 10)
```

The `toFixed(1)` would be great for your purpose

Comment: I'll try it. it's possible to change the number to X? ex. 408x

Comment: `Math.round(408.847345345) + 'x';` would get that job done.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work? It seems to support a lot of different formats and postfixing of symbols (which I think is what you're asking for).

http://mottie.github.io/javascript-number-formatter/